# Need help loading plugin reader/writer for ImageIO

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am building a java ImageIO wrapper around the OpenJPEG native library.

I have a working ImageReader implementation. However, I am unable to get
the ImageIO library to load my implementation automatically. Instead, I have
to manually register the class, and then it works.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get ImageIO.scanForPlugins to work properly?

If you want to take a look at the code, just clone my branch from here

https://github.com/CodecCentral/openjpeg/tree/java_imageio

There are two maven projects inside: one for the reader, and one for a simple viewer
that links to the reader.

You can also find sample Jpeg2000 files here:

https://github.com/CodecCentral/openjpeg-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `META-INF/services/` resources needed for the service registry to pick up your Spi classes.

The resources are text files, and need to be named after the Spi class they implement (one for writer and one for reader), and contain one single line with the exact name of your Spi implementation class.

You need the following files (in java_imageio/wrapping/java/openjp2/src/main/resources):

`/META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi`

```
# File content (comments allowed)
org.openJpeg.JP2KOpenJpegImageReaderSpi
```

`/META-INF/services/javax.imageio.spi.ImageWriterSpi`

```
# File content (comments allowed)
org.openJpeg.JP2KOpenJpegImageWriterSpi
```

---

Some additional comments: While not directly related to registration, I browsed your source code, and there might be some other issues with your Spi class.

- For `inputTypes` you list `File`, `byte[]` and `URL`. While these types might be okay, `ImageIO` will likely require you to support `ImageInputStream` as well (most readers only support this), for normal operation. See the static `read` methods on `ImageIO`, and how they are implemented.
- The `canDecodeInput` is supposed to look into the file/stream contents to recognize format "magic" identifiers or header structure. If you simply return `true`, your reader will try to decode any `File`, `byte[]` and `URL` regardless of content, not giving other readers a chance to properly read them. And again, I think you have to support `ImageInputStream` as input for normal operation.
- (I assume the hardcoded JNI paths are only temporay.. :-)

Comment: Thanks, Harald.  Yeah, this is a work in progress at the moment. Just want to get it working, then polish.

Comment: Harald, thanks so much for reviewing my code. It helped me immensely. I have canDecodeInput working correctly now.  And I remove the hard coded JNI paths :)  all is good !

Comment: My own won't show up, I have the reader meta-inf file with my provider class and the module-info file that provides the reader and requires java.desktop. I can not figure out what might be wrong with mine.

Comment: @gudenau Neither can I, with the given information. Please ask a question with the relevant details, and I'll try to answer. :-)

Comment: I can not ask a question, as I posted (then deleted) some very technical questions that no one answered. But I have a module that has `provides javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi with net.gudenau.imageioreader.Provider`. ImageIO does not pick up on it when it is in the module path.